# How can I have tab 1 and 4 selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

I have two tab sections and I would like the first tab of each tab section to be selected by default. In this case tab 1 and tab 4 . How can I do that?

In my attempted I created a for loop selecting by class name, but I noticed only the last element in the loop is always selected not all. I did not included it as i think the issues is that only one tab can be selected at a time, but I do not see where this statement is.

Just picked up js a week ago. This a modified example i got from w3schools.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}

/* Style the close button */
.topright {
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.topright:hover {color: red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click on the x button in the top right corner to close the current tab:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen1">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">x</span>
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">x</span>
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">x</span>
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<p>Click on the x button in the top right corner to close the current tab:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '1')" id="defaultOpen2">1</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '2')">2</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '3')">3</button>
</div>

<div id="1" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">x</span>
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="2" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">x</span>
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="3" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">x</span>
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen1").click();
document.getElementById("defaultOpen2").click();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no tab 4 .. You simply have 3 tabs in the first section and 3 tabs in second section !

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant the 1st tab for each section open by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you click on the tabs links you are making the call globally, so javascript starts looking for the classes tabContent and hides all of them, even if they are not the one you wanted to hide, to solve this problem you can wrap the tabs in a div and when you click on the tablink first find which is the ID of the tab container you have and then find the right content to show and hide. I made a few tweaks in the code.

Note: This is a solution, but certainly there's a better way to do this tabs

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    var parent = evt.target.parentNode.parentNode.className;
    console.log(parent);
    tabcontent = document.querySelectorAll("." + parent + " .tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.querySelectorAll("." + parent + " .tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
//    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";


    document.querySelector("." + parent +" #" + cityName).style.display = "block";
//    console.log(this)
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen1").click();
document.getElementById("defaultOpen2").click();
```

```css
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}

/* Style the close button */
.topright {
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.topright:hover {color: red;}
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click on the x button in the top right corner to close the current tab:</p>
<div class="cities">
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen1">London</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
  </div>


  <div id="London" class="tabcontent">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">x</span>
    <h3>London</h3>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">x</span>
    <h3>Paris</h3>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
  </div>

  <div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">x</span>
    <h3>Tokyo</h3>
    <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Click on the x button in the top right corner to close the current tab:</p>

<div class="countries">
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'one')" id="defaultOpen2">1</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'two')">2</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'three')">3</button>
  </div>

  <div id="one" class="tabcontent">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">x</span>
    <h3>London</h3>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="two" class="tabcontent">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">x</span>
    <h3>Paris</h3>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
  </div>

  <div id="three" class="tabcontent">
    <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">x</span>
    <h3>Tokyo</h3>
    <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood what you meant. But here is a working fiddle.

I would advice you to add a container DIV for your tabs so it becomes easier to get the first element with javascript.

Let me know if you need anything else.

```js
window.openCity = function (evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}


document.getElementById("London").style.display='block';
 document.getElementById("1").style.display='block';
```

```css
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover,
div.tab button.active{
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}

/* Style the close button */
.topright {
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.topright:hover {color: red;}
```

```html
<p>Click on the x button in the top right corner to close the current tab:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(this, 'London');" id="defaultOpen1">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">x</span>
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">x</span>
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">x</span>
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<p>Click on the x button in the top right corner to close the current tab:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '1')" id="defaultOpen2">1</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '2')">2</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, '3')">3</button>
</div>

<div id="1" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">x</span>
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="2" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">x</span>
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="3" class="tabcontent">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="topright">x</span>
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[not native english speaker]

Hi there. What is happening is that you're using the two tabs like just one. You need to isolate each tab and make some changes in the code so it will work as you want.

Here's the gist with comments in the parts that have changed:
https://gist.github.com/rdlagemann/720614ca5ca29726a9f671c0dd2d2385

Hope it helps!